# Почему форма виснет Async Await

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Изучаю многопоточность и для примера набросал небольшую форму с кнопкой и текстбоксом.

Вот пример метода, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.newsru.com/");

    var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync();

    var readStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    string x = await readStream.ReadToEndAsync();

    textBox1.Text += x; 

}
```

Но форма все равно подвисает. Почему это так происходит?

Comment: Есть шанс, что проблема в другом месте.

Comment: У меня не подвисает, ну есть лаг небольшой буквально микроскопический, но тут и понятно - асинхронное != многопоточное - код выполняется в UI потоке же.

Comment: Получается UI надо выводить в отдельный поток?

Comment: @Сергей: Эээ... А где конкретно код, который приводит к задержке?

Comment: Судя по всему, подвисает она в тот момент, когда вы заносите в textbox дофига текста. Если заменить в коде `textBox1.Text += x;` например на `textBox1.Text = "hello";` то у меня ничего не подвисает. То есть асинхронная часть кода у вас нормально работает.

Comment: Да, именно. Очень дофига текста - слегка подвисат. Совсем чуть чуть, можно даже не заметить. Заметил потому, что анимацию добавил.